# ls reports nonexistent files first, ignoring the specified order

Tags: ls, error-handling

```
$ ls -lU a.txt test.sh badtest
ls: cannot access 'badtest': No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 gqqnbig gqqnbig 11 Apr 15 17:17 a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 gqqnbig gqqnbig 11 Apr 16 17:22 test.sh
```

Although the order of the arguments is `a.txt test.sh badtest`, ls reports `badtest` first.

Is it possible for ls to honor the order of the files? ie. output like

```
$ ls -lU a.txt test.sh badtest
-rw-r--r-- 1 gqqnbig gqqnbig 11 Apr 15 17:17 a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 gqqnbig gqqnbig 11 Apr 16 17:22 test.sh
ls: cannot access 'badtest': No such file or directory
```

Comment: i guess, we cannot change the behavior of ls command as it was written in the way of showing the error messages first. i am not expert of c programming. but here is the code for ls command https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't in one `ls` invocation. Also note that the errors are output on a different stream, stderr where the buffering works differently than on stdout.

Also note that `-U` is non-standard (a GNU extension), and that if you want `ls` to list the files given as argument, you need the `-d` option, otherwise for files of type *directory*, `ls` would list their content instead.

Alternatively, you could run `ls` on each file:

```
for file in a.txt test.sh badtest
  ls -ld -- "$file"
done
```

That would address all those problems above.